# How to SUM products price in this query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a query

```sql
SELECT SUM(product.price)
FROM cart, product
WHERE cart.idUser = :idUser AND cart.idProduct = product.id
```

If someone buys 2 of the same products in one order this query only sums 1 time the price.
eg: 3 same products ordered = 3*10$, query returns only 10$

If someone buys 2 different products the query works fine.
eg: 2 different products = 1*5$ AND 1*10$, query returns 15$

I have these tables:

1. User
2. Order with columnns: id, idUser, value
3. Cart with columnns: idUser, idProduct, quantity
4. Product with columnns: id,name,price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply price with quantity

```
SELECT SUM(quantity * product.price)
FROM cart c
JOIN product p ON c.idProduct = p.id
WHERE cart.idUser = :idUser
```

and use modern JOIN in your queries as above